# External library in my library

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

I am building a android library using android studio. I would like to know if  there is a way to include other external library dependencies to my library.

Say I want to use OkHttp library, but I don't want users of my library to use that dependency in their gradle explicitly.

I searched for couple of hours but couldn't find any useful information. Can anyone help, it would be of great help even if you could give some useful links.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: keep your .jar file in project/apps/libs folder and enjoy

Comment: The best way it to publish your library (artifact) in a maven repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Put the jar into the libs folder.
2. Right click it and hit 'Add as library'
3. Ensure that compile files('libs/lib_name.jar') is in your build.gradle file
4. Do a clean build.

Comment: hey, I totally forgot that this exists after started using gradle. Thank you.

Comment: It is true only if you are using jar files. It doesn't work with aar files.